# python3 'Type function is not iterable' tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm doing a GUI in python with tkinter, and I want to do +1 for every click on the buttons. This is the complete code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

cat=tk.Button(window, text='Cat', height=2)
cat.config()
cat.pack(fill=X)
cube=tk.Button(window, text='Cube',  height=2)
cube.config()
cube.pack(fill=X)
def printed(event):
    print('Clicked!')
def clickbtn():
    cat.bind("<Button-1>", printed)
    cat.bind("<Button-2>", printed)
    cat.bind("<Button-3>", printed)
    cube.bind("<Button-1>", printed)
    cube.bind("<Button-2>", printed)
    cube.bind("<Button-3>", printed)
clickbtn()

for event in clickbtn:
    x=0
    x=x+1
window.mainloop()
```

Is working python 3.6 on windows 10.

Comment: I fail to see how this code (not even a proper [mcve] FWIW] could "work".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm sorry, I edited it now, I putted some code, so you can execute it.

Comment: @ArionSintesSintes You're still missing `window` and `X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clickbtn` is a function, so it's indeed not iterable, and all it does is to bind button clicks to a callback function anyway - it doesn't receive any event whatsoever.

The solution here is quite simply to use the callback you bind to button clicks to update your variable:

```
x = 0

def onclick(event):
    global x
    x += 1
    print('Clicked!')


def set_clickbtn_callback():
    for target in (cat, bind):
       for i in range(1, 3):
          btn = "<Button-{}>".format(i) 
          target.bind(btn, onclick)

set_clickbtn_callback()

window.mainloop()
```